# No module named 'utils_nlp' when using MS nlp_recipes in google colab

Tags: python, nlp, google-colaboratory, recipe

I want to use the utils_nlp provided in the [nlp_recipes](https://github.com/microsoft/nlp-recipes) github repo from MS in my google colab project. However, I'm getting a "No module named 'utils_nlp'" error. This is what I have tried:

In the [setup](https://github.com/microsoft/nlp-recipes/blob/master/SETUP.md) from nlp_recipes is stated that:

> It is also possible to install directly from Github, which is the best way to utilize the utils_nlp package in external projects (while still reflecting updates to the source as it's installed as an editable '-e' package).

> pip install -e git+git@github.com:microsoft/nlp-recipes.git@master#egg=utils_nlp

In colab I run

```
!pip install -e git+https://github.com/microsoft/nlp-recipes.git@master#egg=utils_nlp
```

Which works perfectly

> Obtaining utils_nlp from git+https://github.com/microsoft/nlp
> recipes.git@master#egg=utils_nlp Cloning
> https://github.com/microsoft/nlp-recipes.git (to revision master) to ./src/utils-nlp
> Running command git clone -q https://github.com/microsoft/nlp-recipes.git /content/src/utils-nlp
> Installing build dependencies ... done
> Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
> Preparing wheel metadata ... done
> Installing collected packages: utils-nlp
> Running setup.py develop for utils-nlp
> Successfully installed utils-nlp

When I do `!pip list` I get

> utils-nlp                2.0.0           /content/src/utils-nlp

When I want to import from utils-nlp, for example

```
from utils_nlp.dataset.preprocess import to_lowercase, to_spacy_tokens
```

I get a

> No module named 'utils_nlp'

I have tried using `sys.path.append("/content/src/")`  and many other paths to append but none of those seem to work.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Restart your runtime after install and prior to import.

Restart command is:
[image]

A full worked example is:[image]